# Is it possible to sort non-stackable items in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

[Item Sorters](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Hopper#Item_sorter) are super sweet.  But, I have a skeleton farm, and am getting tons of non-stackable drops.  Since armor can be smelted into iron/gold, I'd like to smelt those drops in a furnace, and burn bows in a furnace.  And trash all leather armor.  Is there a way to sort out these non-stackable items in vanilla survival?

Comment: It has been a while since Fabian answered.  Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: @IronAnvil Not really.  Fabian's answer is partial, but gets at the key point.  There's no "universal" sorter, but a couple of "partial" tricks.  So, I abandonded my "universal" approach, and just have some partials in key areas.  It helps, it's not ideal.  An exhaustive list of tricks would be awesome....

Comment: What partial tricks have you employed?  I like your idea with the grinder.  Are you still doing most of it manually?

Comment: @IronAnvil Nothing beyond what Fabian says below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no one way for all of them, but most can be sorted using different tricks: Armour and weapons can be equipped to zombies and unequipped again, potions and water bottles can be filtered using a brewing stand, shulker boxes can be placed and broken automatically and so on.

For now, please just look up " sorter" for all of them on YouTube, I'll expand this answer later once I've figured it out for all items myself.

Comment: Okay, that helps a lot.  Turns out only burnable items will load from a hopper into a furnace.  So, that's half of the problem very neatly solved (does require some redstone.)  I haven't figured out smeltable or not though.

Comment: But you can't take it out of the furnace automatically.

Comment: Since, I "want" all burnable items to go to the furnace, that works out well for me....

Comment: How does one equip and unequip a zombie with redstone?

Comment: Throw it to him, then throw something else to him. Thanks to [MC-44283](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-44283) you can make him get rid of the item again. I don't know if the swapping back and forth still works, but [here's a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=StW14HlMtsQ). If it doesn't work, you'll likely need one zombie per successfully sorted item, so you would need to connect your sorting system to a spawner or mob farm.

Comment: I will update this answer one day, but probably not too soon. 1.13 will probably arrive earlier than a proper answer by me. Maybe even 2019.

Comment: Wow, I keep getting upvotes for this, even though I didn't even make the whole list yet. :D It might not even happen this year, I have a lot of other things planned.

Comment: As of 1.15, it's possible to deploy armorstands and equip them with armor using dispensers. Non armor/weapon items will be dropped, the rest is equipped and then you can break the armorstand with an arrow to drop all the armor (and recycle the armorstand for reuse). One problem is it works with leather and diamond armor just as well as with smeltable variants.

Comment: There was a way with zombies, but the principle that allowed you to keep reusing the same zombie might be broken.

Answer (score 1):

A temporary solution for armor, it can be dispensed onto an armor stand, then use a cobweb to catch the non armor items into a hopper for further sorting. Only problem is you can only have so many armor stands. After the farming is complete you could break the armor stands (by hand or from dispensed arrows) and sort them afterwards, and reload your stands back into position manually.

When you place a hopper under a brewing stand, it will remove the water bottles before the brewing commences.

Bows and fishing rods are fuel for furnaces.

I have no solutions for saddles or enchanted books yet.

Comment: The armour stand idea is really valuable now (in 1.15), because armour stands can be summoned by dispensers!

Answer (score 1):

You can actually sort unstackable items using a design using allays by silentwhisperer. I’m not sure if he created it, but that’s where I saw it first. It works in Bedrock, and I *think* it works in Java Edition, as well.
(See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GPK1MuyhkkY)).

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular sorter (

) to sort out arrows and then bone and the armor and bows end up in the last , Junk chest on the end. Also there is a way to filter out all non-stackable items in the middle of the sorting line up (

) but those non-stackable items can not be further sorted by hoppers. Hope this helps
GL, webyankee

Answer (score -2):

Designs I found for filtering non-stacking items didn't work for me in Java Edition, but this seems to. The redstone torch, like in the design in the video, will burn out if it flashes too much, but if you use a comparator as a NOT gate, then it won't burn out. You put a weak signal into a comparator and subtract a strong signal that is put into the side when a non-stacking item is in the hopper.

[image: screenshot of the design described above]